# Typescript compiles fail with error "Duplicate Identifier"

Tags: javascript, typescript, karma-runner

I have some problem with karma runner. When it compiles the source from .ts to .js files. I fact a problem that when I use 'declare' keyword to declare a class that is defined in another file, the error "Duplicate identifier" occurs. For instance:

> file_1.ts:

```
class Test {...}
```

> file_2.ts

```
declare var Test
class Something{
    value: Test
    constructor(){}
}
```

I research that we can use "reference path" to solve it, but, I use server-side render and include the resource per one file not all of them. So, I see that with this solution, when I compile the to js files, I assume that it will include all code of them and increase my file size. Could somebody help me :(? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

P/S: Sorry about my poor English.

Comment: Try `declare class Test`, as `Test` is not a `var`?

Comment: @Bergi This doesn't work  :(

Comment: Did you get a different error message at least?

Comment: This error is expected. You may not introduce a class twice in the same scope. I think you misunderstand the purpose of the `declare` construct. Please explain your use case more clearly.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I got "Can not find the name". But, I do some demo and try to use "reference path" and it not include all my code of the declared class. Maybe, it can solve my problem because i assume that it will include all my codes into one file.So, I will try it tomorrow when I come to the company. If it's Ok, I will update this question. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AluanHaddad In my case, I compile the .ts files and include them into the template (.html). I only compile each file individually. So, I use "declare" to tell the compiler that this class is defined elsewhere and it work fine!. But, If i compile all project and their dependencies when run unit test, it's catch this error. Could you recommend for me some ideas ?

Comment: I need more information to make a recommendation detailed enough to approach an answer.  there is no reason that you should need to  declare a class that you also define. My advice to you would be to embrace modern JavaScript and start using a module system. That will deal with all of your dependency issues. `/// <reference path="..." />` is neither reliable nor scalable and should be avoided as the plague

Comment: @KNguyen would you accept rewrite your app using modules as an answer?

Comment: @Aluan Haddad I think it’s impossible now, because my project is going to make a demo for client :(

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with it except maybe you don't have time to do things correctly. Get it right next time